# Why is my custom shader drawing the editor lines on top of the object?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, hlsl

I wrote a custom shader in Unity URP 2022.2 and otherwise it works fine, but the editor grid lines are being drawn on top of the object in the editor window.

[image: Lines on top of the white circle]

The shader code I used was like this:

```
Shader "Custom/SurfaceShaderExample2"
{
    Properties
    {
        [MainColor] _BaseColor("Base Color", Color) = (1, 1, 1, 1)
    }
    SubShader
    {
        Tags {"RenderType"="Opaque" "RenderPipeline" = "UniversalPipeline" "Queue"="Geometry"}

        Pass {
            Name "ForwardLit"
            Tags { "LightMode" = "UniversalForward" }

            Cull Back
            Blend One Zero
            ZTest LEqual
            ZWrite On

            HLSLPROGRAM
            
            #pragma vertex Vertex
            #pragma fragment Fragment

            #include "Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal/ShaderLibrary/Core.hlsl"

            struct VertexInput {
                float3 positionOS : POSITION;
            };

            struct Varyings {
                float4 positionHCS : SV_POSITION;
            };

            CBUFFER_START(UnityPerMaterial)
                half4 _BaseColor;
            CBUFFER_END

            Varyings Vertex(VertexInput IN) {
                Varyings OUT;

                OUT.positionHCS = TransformObjectToHClip(IN.positionOS);

                return OUT;
            }

            float4 Fragment(Varyings IN) : SV_TARGET {
                return _BaseColor;
            }

            ENDHLSL
        }
    }
}
```

The behaviour looks like the object isn't writing to depth, but it works fine with other objects. The only problem is with the editor grid.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to have been that I didn't include a depth only pass in the shader. When I added the depth pass it works even in the editor window.

```
Pass {
    Name "Depth"
    Tags { "LightMode" = "DepthOnly" }

    Cull Back
    ZTest LEqual
    ZWrite On
    ColorMask R

    HLSLPROGRAM
            
    #pragma vertex Vertex
    #pragma fragment Fragment

    #include "../Common/SurfaceShaderExampleDepthProgram.hlsl"

    ENDHLSL 
}
```

The pass just outputs the clipspace z coordinate.